# Why is there a margin on these links? CSS

Tags: html, css, margins

Here's the JSFiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/bozdoz/k2enx/

Margin for `#topLinks a` is set to 0, so I don't see why there is a space between the links.  I set the background to red so you can see the margins.

[image]

I would like to remove the blue vertical lines in between the anchor elements.  I have done this before, but I can't seem to get it to work in this circumstance for some reason.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not margin, its a space. As the links are inline elements any whitespace between them is converted into a single space. Remove newlines from between the links:

```
<a href="#">Home</a><a href="#">Profession</a><a href="#">about</a>
```

Comment: Wow.  I knew it must be an easy fix.  I didn't realize that the new lines would affect the document.  Is it only anchor tags that this would affect?

Comment: Any inline elements are affected. If you remove the formatting it becomes obvious (you wouldn't want the page to read "HomeProfessionabout").

Comment: I'm not sure that that makes it obvious.  The fact that they blend together without formatting makes me think that the new lines are insignificant.  When do the new lines affect it?  When I add padding?

Comment: No, I mean that if you *don't* have newlines they blend together. Any whitespace adds a space between them.

Comment: Ah. Yes I see that. Sorry for the mix up. Never knew that new lines affected html.  Learned something new.  And thanks! :)